# What are the supported protocols in SecureSocket?

Tags: http, websocket, dart

When looking at the documentation of [`SecureSocket`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-io/SecureSocket-class.html), I see there's a parameter in the methods `secure`/`connect`/`secureServer` called `supportedProtocols`.

- What is it?
- What are the possible values?
- Is the order important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **What is it?**

   A list of protocols that the client supports for secure communication
2. **What are the possible values?**

   Names of protocols and versions separated by a slash (e.g. `"http/1.1"`)
3. **Is the order important?**

   Yes. The precedence is set in descending order

**Some explanation:**

`TLS` has an extension called `ALPN` which (as the name suggests) is used to negotiate the application layer protocol to be used for the secure communication.

In `ALPN` the protocols are identified using the format I specified above.

`SecureSocket` implements `TLS` and therefore has to receive the protocol list parameter to be used in the `ALPN` stage.

Unless your server and client are implementing a custom communication protocol I would recommend you just use `"http/1.1"`.

**More info:**

The only documentation of the protocol list passed to `SecureServer` I could find in the Dart sources is at `SecurityContext._protocolsToLengthEncoding` (`io/security_context.dart:190`):

```
/// Encodes a set of supported protocols for ALPN/NPN usage.
///
/// The `protocols` list is expected to contain protocols in descending order
/// of preference.
///
/// See RFC 7301 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301) for the encoding of
/// `List<String> protocols`:
///     opaque ProtocolName<1..2^8-1>;
///
///     struct {
///         ProtocolName protocol_name_list<2..2^16-1>
///     } ProtocolNameList;
///
/// The encoding of the opaque `ProtocolName<lower..upper>` vector is
/// described in RFC 2246: 4.3 Vectors.
///
/// Note: Even though this encoding scheme would allow a total
/// `ProtocolNameList` length of 65535, this limit cannot be reached. Testing
/// showed that more than ~ 2^14  bytes will fail to negotiate a protocol.
/// We will be conservative and support only messages up to (1<<13)-1 bytes.
```

Going through [RFC 7301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301) (`ALPN` description):

```
"ProtocolNameList" contains the list of protocols advertised by the
client, in descending order of preference.  Protocols are named by
IANA-registered, opaque, non-empty byte strings, as described further
in Section 6 ("IANA Considerations") of this document.
```

And [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301#section-6):

```
Protocol:  HTTP/1.1
Identification Sequence:
   0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x2f 0x31 0x2e 0x31 ("http/1.1")
Reference:  [RFC7230]

Protocol:  SPDY/1
Identification Sequence:
   0x73 0x70 0x64 0x79 0x2f 0x31 ("spdy/1")
Reference:
   http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft1

Protocol:  SPDY/2
Identification Sequence:
   0x73 0x70 0x64 0x79 0x2f 0x32 ("spdy/2")
Reference:
   http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2
```

The "Identification Sequence" is the protocol identifier in ASCII bytes. It is the raw data sent in the negotiation stage through the socket.

Fun fact: In Dart the `SecurityContext._protocolsToLengthEncoding` method is what encodes the protocol identifiers from string to bytes.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

Historically unencrypted application protocols were usually assigned their own port (e.g. `80` for `http`, `25` for `smtp`).

**ALPN**: Nowadays most traffic is encrypted via TLS which is a secure transport protocol. Any application protocol can use it. Instead of using new port numbers for application protocols a different solution is available: TLS supports an extension known as **ALPN (Application-Level Protocol Negotiation)** which allows client/server to tell the peer which protocols they support and what they prefer (possibly with a fallback to a protocol deduced by the port number -- which is great for backwards compatibility)

(Side note: There was also a precursor TLS extension known as NPN "Next Protocol Negotiation" serving a similar purpose, but it is deprecated for various reasons)

**Most common use case is http/2**: Servers listen on port `443` and offer to speak `http/1.1`, `http/2` and let's say `spdy`. The browser will make a TCP connection to server port `443` and let's the server know which protocols it supports. The server will then choose which protocol to speak (based on the list the client sent and what the server application supports). For backwards compatibility, client/browsers will fallback to `http/1.1` if no protocol was negotiated.

**Negogiation & Priority** There are 3 cases:

- Client or Server does not support the ALPN extension: No protocol was negogiated
- Client and Server support ALPN but have no common protocol: No protocol was neogogated
- Client and Server support ALPN and there is one or more protocols both support: The protocol with highest priority is taken.

**Dart support**: Dart added support for ALPN some time ago and exposes it  via the optional named `supportedProtocols` parameter to

- [SecureSocket.conect](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-io/SecureSocket/connect.html) for the client part
- [SecureServer.bind](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-io/SecureServerSocket/bind.html) for the server part

Once a TLS connection has been established, both ends will be able to see the negogiated protocol via [SecureSocket.selectedProtocol](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-io/SecureSocket/selectedProtocol.html). If the peer does not support the ALPN TLS extension or there was no common protocol, then `selectedProtocol` will be `null`.

The protocols in `supportedProtocols` are specified in decreasing preference (the first one in the list which is common between server/client will be chosen).

**ALPN identifiers** There are no real restrictions on what the protocol identifiers can be. Your application can use its own. Though for public protocols, usually RFCs will recommend which identifiers to use, for example [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) specifies in [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.1):

"The string "h2" identifies the protocol where HTTP/2 uses Transport Layer Security (TLS)"

**Inspect it yourself**: If you are very curious you can use a network packet inspector, like newer versions of [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark), to inspect TLS traffic and see what ALPN protocols are offered.